# How to convert string into SPUser?

Tags: object-model, user, spuser

I have a string "System Account", how can I convert the string into SPUser?

I've tried SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser("System Account") and also web.AllUser["System Account"] but hit error.

Please help, thank you in advanced.

Comment: I've tried SPWeb.AllUsers.GetByID(userID).ID.ToString() and it solved my issue, I should have use userID instead of user name in string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the system account by [SPSite property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.systemaccount.aspx)

```
SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount
```

Basicaly EnsureUser method uses logon name (Domain\User_Alias) of the user.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what if I do not have Domain\User_Alias? I only have the welcome name in string format? is it still possible I validate and convert into SPUser?

Comment: I do not sure, but welcom name is not an unique name... if it is true, i think that it is not possible.

Comment: One way is to loop through all siteusers, but this solution is a performance killer (

Answer (score 3):

i guess you are looking for some api to resolve inputs.
try this utility method:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal
```

it will return a SPPrincipal object, witch contains a "LoginName" property.
then you can use SPWeb.EnsureUser(loginName) to get a SPUser object.

more infomation about this method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.resolveprincipal.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try this, should work

```
string strUser = “Shiva Bala”;

//(myWeb is your SPWeb object)

SPFieldUserValue flduserVal = new SPFieldUserValue(myWeb, strUser);

SPUser myUser = flduserVal.User;
```

plus can someone tell me how to do it if there is a domain user?

Comment: You can not pass the display name as argument to SPFieldUsesrValue constructor. This requires item value (e.g. "12#;Shiva Bala"). With respect to question, Basically, one need to pass Logon Name as parameter in EnsureUser method. And for fetching user, one should use "SPWeb.AllUsers.GetByID(loginName)".